# Hide livepatch indicator in top panel

Tags: indicator, canonical-livepatch

After updating Ubuntu packages today, I see a new livepatch indicator in the top-panel:

[image: livepatch indicator]

How can I hide it? I tried running `sudo apt remove indicator-livepatch`, but there's no such package. When I go to livepatch settings, I don't see an option to hide the indicator, just a button for sign-in.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

From [Ubuntu's Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/bkndho/how_can_i_remove_the_livepatch_appindicator/):

1. Run `dconf-editor`.
2. Navigate to **com > ubuntu > update-notifier**.
3. Set `show-livepatch-status-icon` to off.

Programmatically you can run this within terminal for an equal effect.

```
gsettings set com.ubuntu.update-notifier show-livepatch-status-icon false
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, though after setting the value an entry in `~/.config/dconf/user` can be found. Even a reboot didn't help. I'm using LXQt on top of Openbox, but I'm not sure this matters.

Comment: Follow-up: This should have been fixed with [update-notifier 3.192.1.7](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/bionic/main/proposed/update-notifier) for Bionic 18.04, but this version is already installed here.