# How can I remove live patch notification?

Tags: uninstall, notification, notification-area, canonical-livepatch

I just upgraded the packages on my 18.04 machine and after reboot I see a new symbol in my top right that looks like a shield with a red "denied" symbol on it.
[image]

After further investigation this turns out to be the icon for the "livepatch" feature. It is notifying me that "livepatch" is off, and urges me to register to enable it.

I have zero interest in livepatch. I never opted to install this feature. I guess if I don't do something this shield will stay annoying and in-my-face 24/7-365?

Anyway I need help to **remove it permanently like it never existed in the first place**. Like completely deleted from my OS. Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT-1: Clarification in case you think I want to simply hide the notification. I actually want to **COMPLETELY OBLITERATE IT** and leave behind only unlinked inodes.

EDIT-2: I don't have livepatch installed. In fact look at this screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I vote this to not be a duplicate because I don't want to hide it. I want (as is clearly stated in the question) to completely remove it.

Comment: You can uninstall livepatch using `sudo snap remove canonical-livepatch`

Comment: @Kulfy: Thanks! However I don't have livepatch installed. I added a screenshot to question!

Comment: Perhaps you have it but not as a snap, do you have `/usr/lib/systemd/user/update-notifier-livepatch.service`. It seems that you must have `/usr/lib/update-notifier/livepatch-notification`? Perhaps `sudo ubuntu-advantage disable-livepatch -r` is what you seek (from that apps man page).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide livepatch indicator in top panel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140848/hide-livepatch-indicator-in-top-panel)

Comment: I've also removed the`'ubuntu-advantage-tools` package

Answer (score 8):

It may be that you don't have livepatch installed as clarified in the question but the gnome top bar icon is still showing, here is the solution:

Run this command in terminal to remove the livepatch icon in the top bar in Ubuntu.

```
gsettings set com.ubuntu.update-notifier show-livepatch-status-icon false
```

In comments I read that livepatch may not be a snap package but by default livepatch snap package is installed in Ubuntu, I haven't found any non-snap package of livepatch. But, I suggest you keep livepatch in the system as it installs and applies critical Linux kernel security updates without rebooting your system.

[Source 1](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/bkndho/how_can_i_remove_the_livepatch_appindicator/)

[Source 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140848/hide-livepatch-indicator-in-top-panel)

Comment: Didn't work for me; see comments on https://askubuntu.com/a/1140850/568304 for details.

Comment: @Murphy I'm guessing the patch fixed it?

Comment: Yep, after a full-upgrade and a reboot the issue was fixed, don't know why it occurred in the first place.

Comment: @Flimm For me the issue isn't fixed yet, though the installed version is supposed to be the right one.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use dconf-editor to remove the Livepatch notification icon.

If you don't have it,

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

1. Open dconf-editor.
2. Go to 'com > ubuntu > update-notifier >
   show-livepatch-status-icon' (or just start typing "livepatch" after
   opening dconf-editor).
3. You have an on/off switch for the
   notification icon.

This disables (or enables) the notification icon. It does not remove or turns off Livepatch.