# Removing the Livepatch system tray panel indicator in Lubuntu 20.04

Tags: lubuntu, system-tray, lxqt, canonical-livepatch, clutter

I'm using LXQt in Lubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa.

I'd like to get rid of the Livepatch indicator, that's within the system tray that's on my panel (the tray is full of c*** I don't need anyway!)

I looked for answers here:

- [How can I remove live patch notification?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1142910/how-can-i-remove-live-patch-notification)
- https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/bkndho/how_can_i_remove_the_livepatch_appindicator/
- [Two updater icons in Lubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1287925/two-updater-icons-in-lubuntu-20-04)
- [Hide livepatch indicator in top panel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140848/hide-livepatch-indicator-in-top-panel)

but the suggestions did not work, or were not about removing livepatch.

I don't mind disabling it completely, or just removing the icon. And it can be just for my user, or globally.

Comment: https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/5/5.1/lxqt-panel.html?highlight=panel   Refer to "*Configure Panel*", though I tend to right-click the panel nearer the left of mine to make changes, as the menu varies on what you're over or near and my own setup is less cluttered to the left so I get the configure/add/etc options I can't seem to get to the right...  I've not used *live-patch* so have no idea how it appears on panel, that may require manual edit to remove that 'notification'   (`~/.config/lxqt/panel.conf` etc)

Comment: @guiverc: That's a long document which doesn't tell you how to configure which widgets load into the system tray. The config file doesn't say anything about what's in the tray, either. But - I've clarified in the question that the livepatch icon is on the system tray.

Comment: The link was to the Lubuntu manual; as I stated I've no experience with *live-patch* so have no idea how it associates itself to the panel etc.  For autostart I'd look in LXQt Session Settings (https://manual.lubuntu.me/stable/3/3.2/3.2.13/session_settings.html?highlight=autostart) as that's where you'll find the Lubuntu update notifier etc (and where I'd disable that; you just click/unclick them, then can logout/login to see if it achieved what you want etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to remove the Livepatch system tray panel indicator in Lubuntu 20.04 disabling some options in autostart, similar to the comments of @guiverc to the original question. In lxqt configuration center, under session configuration options: autostart.

I disabled:

- upgNotifier: /usr/lib/lubuntu-update-notifier/lubuntu-upg-notifier.sh
- Update notifier: update-notifier
- Ubuntu report try to sends metrics data on release upgrade: /usr/bin/ubuntu-report send upgrade

[How to enter lxqt configuration center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p08X9.png)

[How to disable updates notifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wd2AR.png)

Answer (score -3):

If I read you correctly, to disable "Livepatch (Canonical Livepatch Service)"

```
ubuntu-advantage disable-livepatch -r
```

this will Disable the Livepatch service. If the -r option is given,  the  canonical-livepatch snap will be removed after the service is disabled.
Would have been easier/better if Dconf would have worked to hide the icon though.
I don't use lubuntu sorry.

Comment: There is no such ubuntu-advantage command as `disable-livepatch`.

Comment: And there is no such switch as `-r`.

Comment: And if I run `ubuntu-advantage disable livepatch`, it says I can't even use ubuntu-advantage without a subscription.

Answer (score -3):

Sorry about that:
Will this work then:

```
sudo canonical-livepatch disable
```

Or

```
sudo snap run canonical-livepatch disable
```

I've used both with sucess

Comment: `Command 'canonical-livepatch' not found` ... and `error: cannot find current revision for snap canonical-livepatch: readlink /snap/canonical-livepatch/current: no such file or directory`.