# Livepatch error

Tags: canonical-livepatch

I have been using Ubuntu 18.04 and lately there has been a Livepatch alert top bar icon saying about an error while trying to find updates. The only solution I have found so far is to go to Software and Updates, find the Livepatch tab and turn it off and back on again. After a while, the icon says that no updates were found. Is there a fix for this strange behaviour? Thanks.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1140848/hide-livepatch-indicator-in-top-panel

Answer (score 2):

The same thing happened to me this morning, I also had to turn off the tab and turn it back on, now I have the icon of a shield in the top bar with a green check, like the icon of updates of "Linux Mint". It's a bit weird, and I can't find any information about it.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, it seems that the problem has been fixed, probably through an update. Josh, thanks for your time.